# Change date on a computer that is attached to a domain

Tags: windows, date

Is it possible to change the date of a computer that is attached to a domain and have it stick?  I've researched this for a few days and haven't found anything confirming or denying that this is possible. The computer we have is Windows 10 and the domain controller is Windows Server 2012 R2.  I can provide more details if needed.

Thanks.

Comment: What problem do you want to solve with this?

Comment: If the clock off-set between computers in the domain is more than a 5 minutes your Kerberos based authentication will fail...

Comment: @Sven Usually, people who want to do this are trying to _create_ a problem, not _solve_ a problem. So...what problem do you want to create with this?

Comment: @Sven We would like to advance the date when we run an accounts receivable aging report.

Comment: @HBruijn 5 Minutes?  I had found that it would fail after 5 months...maybe that poster had mistyped since yours sounds way more likely.

Comment: `Is it possible to change the date of a computer that is attached to a domain and have it stick?` - Not really (practically speaking). `We would like to advance the date when we run an accounts receivable aging report` - That sounds a bit on the shady side.

Comment: Since people asked for a use case for this: We needed to simulate an (external) certificate expiring on a development machine, to see if our software would react as expected. Granted, a separate test machine would be more suitable for that, but since the certificate is stored on external, dedicated USB hardware, we couldn't just fire up a VM.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not recommended for a lot of reasons, but here is how to:

First, unregister your time service to not resync. On elevated prompt run:

```
W32TM /unregister
```

Then, change set the time you want using the command `time` and `date`:

```
time 05:23:00 AM
date 5/15/2009
```

Rollback:

```
W32TM /register
W32TM /resync
```

Source:
http://ss64.com/nt/w32tm.html 
http://www.wikihow.com/Change-the-Computer-Time-and-Date-Using-the-Command-Prompt

Edit: Corrected rollback command.

Comment: Are you sure those "rollback" commands are right? ... from what I can gather they should be "w32tm /register" then "w32tm /resync" (not unregister). On my PC, because I had not restarted the system between manually setting time and re-enabling time service, I got an error about the service being marked for deletion. It was necessary to manually stop the windows time service before running the "w32tm /register" command, then it worked and everything seems to be back to domain time again.

Comment: What Daniel Scott said. If you want to script it, it's `net stop w32time` and then, after `w32tm /register`, `net start w32time`.

Answer (score 0):

Why in the world would you want to change the date on a domain-joined computer?

Anyway, yes, you can do that, but any form of domain authentication would automatically fail, because Kerberos really doesn't like that.

If you want to simulate a later date on *your own* computer, that's fine.
But don't try that in a domain.

Comment: It would only automatically fail if the new time was not within the specified offset from the domain (usually 5 minutes.) For example, if you need to use a more accurate time source for some measurement, that should still work as long as your domain isn't off by 5 minutes.